# Получение заголовков таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую. Есть табличка

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">подпись 1</th>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">Подпись 2</th>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">Подпись 3</th>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">Подпись 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">1</th>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element">
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element">
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" class="table-element" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">2</th>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element" >
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element" >
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" class="table-element" >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

внутри в ячейках чекбоксы. Как при нажатии на чекбокс получить верхнюю подпись?( из списка(подпись1, подпись2, и тд.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это можно сделать на `jQuery`, только не очень понятно что у вас с первым столбцом, который выводит цифры, а не чекбоксы, поэтому решил его пропускать, и добавляю единицу `.eq(cellIndex + 1)` при поиске значения, если там тоже будут чекбоксы, то `+ 1` можно убрать.

```js
$('table').on('change', '.table-element', function() {
  var row = $(this).parent().parent();
  var cell = $(this).parent();
  var cellIndex = row.find('td').index(cell);
  var text = $('table tr').eq(0).find('th').eq(cellIndex+1).html();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">подпись 1</th>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">Подпись 2</th>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">Подпись 3</th>
      <th class="horizontal" colspan="1">Подпись 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">1</th>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element">
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element">
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" class="table-element">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">2</th>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element">
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="table-element">
      </td>
      <td colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" class="table-element">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```